# PC freezes when running Steam on dedicated gpu AMD Rx 540

Tags: drivers, graphics, steam, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I have Kubuntu 17.10 on an Acer laptop (Aspire A515-41G-19BF) with hybrid graphics: an integrated AMD Radeon R7 and a dedicated AMD Rx 540 with 2gb ddr5. If I run Steam with the integrated graphics, it works. If I run with the command `DRI_PRIME=1 steam` to use the dedicated graphics card (or if I choose "run on discrete graphics card" from the KDE start menu settings), it works for some 30 seconds and then it freezes the whole pc. The mouse doesn't work anymore, the touchpad moves the pointer but can't click, nothing moves on the screen, and after a minute even the touchpad doesn't work. You can hear the fan moving and nothing else. The only thing to do is disconnecting the power. During the 30 seconds I can access the Steam system information and it correctly shows the Rx 540 (can't make a screenshot because I don't want to disconnect the power for the 4th time).

The same has happened a few times with other applications, but the Rx seems basically to work with Gimp, Shotwell and Gscan2pdf, and not so well with Inkscape. I haven't tried games yet, for obvious reasons.

Do you think installing the Oibaf ppa may solve my problem? If no, do I have to file a bug?

Comment: I've installed the Oibaf ppa and it seemed it didn't work, then I found out big picture mode works. _ONLY_ big picture mode. I have to start Steam with `DRI_PRIME=1 steam -bigpicture`. The default resolution was 1066x600 and I had to change it from the Steam settings, it said I would have bad performance with 1366x768 cause my vram is only 244 MB, but in the Steam big picture mode "system" tab it said my graphics memory is 2 gb, I changed resolution and didn't have bad performance! I guess it's KDE's fault in handling windows without big picture. Still have to try if big p. works without Oibaf

Comment: Big picture mode (=full screen) also works without Oibaf. I can minimize the big picture, so it's not a big problem that I can only use that, but still, it's a bug. Can someone tell me who I have to report it to? KDE?

Comment: Solved with upgrade to 18.04

Answer (score -1):

freezes and instability caused by commit: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/320b164abb32db876866a4ff8c2cb710524ac6ea for RX 540 gpu's.

So for now you can't update to newer kernels than 4.16 .

multiple people including me reported this problem to lkml and bugzilla kernel team but they didn't responded or fixed the problem for a year (they asked for bisecting though) so you can try to report the problem to amd.

last time amd also asked me to bisect the kernel so you can visit https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201077 for more information about what works and what not